# Which way should be selected when move from mysql to mariadb?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysqldump, mariadb-10.2

Now, the mysql version is `5.1`.I plan to move to mariadb `10.2`.Use `mysqldump` and `source` to update databases.
Based on MySQL Upgrade Strategies,

> Upgrading to the latest release is recommended before upgrading to the
>   next version

.
Way 1:`mysql 5.1->mysql 5.7->mariadb 10.2`
Way 2:`mysql 5.1->mariadb 5.1->mariadb 10.2`
Which way is better(less data loss)?

Comment: Better according to what criteria? Why don't you go to MariaDB 10.2 in one step?

Comment: Take a dump of your 5.1 and try and restore it into MariaDB 10.2 and if that fails (unlikely IMHO) use the other route. You'll still have your dump whatever happens!

Comment: Agreed that you can probably go directly from MySQL 5.1 to MariaDB 10.2 with a sql dump file. Maybe don't use the `source` command to import the dump if it's a big database as it prints the results of each statement to the terminal, so might be slow. Instead, if you're on Linux/Unix, run something like this from the Linux/Unix shell: `mysql name_of_database < dumpfile.sql > import.log`

Comment: @Vérace, based on mysql upgrade strategies, `Upgrading to the latest release is recommended before upgrading to the next version`

Comment: Back up, try it, if it fails come back.

Comment: DBA's are fundamentally lazy! :-) Go with my suggestion first - if it doesn't work, what have you got to lose? From what @EvanCarrol has posted, it ebpven seems to be the official way to go!

Comment: Of the two options you mention, moving from `MySQL 5.1` to `MySQL 5.7` matches the "upgrade to latest release before upgrading to new version" description, I would think. If you feel obligated to do this as a two-step process, that is - several people who are better acquainted with MySQL than I am have said a one-step process should be OK.

Comment: Way 1 is not recommended by Oracle.  They want you to do 5.1->5.5->5.6->5.7 before leaving their list.  This is because the upgrades only handle one step at a time.

Comment: There will be problems with any approach.  There have been incompatible changes.  One example: the internal format of `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP`.  None of the incompatibilities are insurmountable; but they could be "bumps in the road".

Comment: Try any approach.  But be sure to be able to restore if you get to a difficult spot.

Answer (score 1):

We can't do anything without a problem except point you to the official information,

- [How to migrate from MySQL to MariaDB on Linux in five steps](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-migrate-mysql-mariadb-linux-five-steps)
- [Migrating to MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/migrating-to-mariadb/)

**Generally the further you are from an original fork the more complexities you'll encounter in the migration. Therefore the earlier the version of MySQL the fewer features of MySQL that are MySQL-specific that you'll have to contend with.** Upgrading to a newer of MySQL before the migration to MariaDB is likely to make your job *harder*.

Answer (score 1):

It's very probable that next sequence would be way more fast and painless comparatively to the software upgrading:

1. `mysqldump` all the databases
2. export all accounts with permissions
3. deinstall `mysql`
4. install `mariadb`
5. import databases and accounts